# clangd doesn't recognize standard headers

Tags: c++, g++, neovim, liskov-substitution-principle, clangd

This question has been asked and answered a bunch of times, but none of the answers seem to work for me.

I've been trying to get `clangd` set up in nvim lsp.  I used [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) to generate `compile_commands.json`, but clangd still gives me errors telling me it can't find standard library headers.
Here's a minimal example:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << "hello clangd";
  return 0;
}
```

I then run: `bear -- g++ main.cpp`, which compiles and creates a `compile_commands.json` with this content:

```
[
  {
    "arguments": [
      "/usr/bin/g++",
      "-c",
      "main.cpp"
    ],
    "directory": "/home/xxx/tmp/hello_clangd",
    "file": "/home/xxx/tmp/hello_clangd/main.cpp"
  }
]
```

I also tried compiling using a cmake flag to generate `compile_commands.json` but I'm getting the same issue. I can get the file but the language server still won't work properly.

I have been able to use clang with [vim-pio](https://github.com/normen/vim-pio) so it seems it's not broken. what am I missing.

EDIT: I'm on ubuntu btw

Comment: I also have this issue when using platformIO in nvim. I'm using the compile_commands.json generated by pio, if I don't use the compile_commands.json then clangd recognizes only the system libraries, but when I include the json file, it recognizes everything but the system libraries. Still usable but pretty frustrating.

Comment: @PierreBaudin Isn't that intended behaviour? Since you're using PIO, I assume you're developing for embedded systems, so you wouldn't expect the system libraries to be available.

Comment: yes I'm doing embedded development, but I am using libraries like cstdint and stdio.

My problem appears to be more subtle than I initially thought. I'm getting LSP errors related to these in my lib and include directories of the pio project. The LSP detects the libraries just fine for files in the src directory. I'm using the compile_commands.json file generated by pio with the "include toolchains" flag high.

This has been the main thing preventing me from moving fully to nvim from vscode. When the vscode intellisense can't find a library it's easy to manually add it to the path.

Comment: I figured out my problem! It appears the "include toolchains" flag doesn't apply to the user defined libraries in the lib directory. I fixed it by manually adding the path to the toolchains into the library.json file in the root of the library's directory

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had a similar issue on Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS using lunarvim 1.2
and Clang++/Clangd seems to look for the newest available libraries, so instead of parsing the "11" directory (which contained "libstdc++"), it parses the "12" directory (which did not contain "libstdc++") for the libraries.

```
ls /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

```
11  12
```

I searched for the version I needed.

```
apt search libstdc++
```

Problem was solved after installing the "libstdc++" for gcc version 12 from the apt repository.

```
apt install libstdc++-12-dev
```

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333823/clang-doesnt-see-basic-headers/29821538#29821538) to solve the issue

Comment: Yes that sounds a lot like my setup. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Kudos! Helped the issue that I was having running clangd via eglot in emacs

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was facing similar error with Helix editor. I tried passing [query-driver](https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/system-headers#query-driver) flag to clangd and also tried inspecting the output of `/usr/bin/gcc -E -xc++ -v /dev/null` ( [see this](https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/system-headers#heuristic-search-for-system-headers) ). The search list contained the `11` directory but still clangd was not picking up the standard header files. Installing libstdc++-12-dev fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution myself using clang++ using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54521402/). The command that works for me is:

```
bear -- clang++ -I/usr/include/c++/11 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11 -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 main.cpp
```

It's still a bit confusing to me so I'm open to better solutions and explanations.